# Take a picture of Augmented Reality Application

Tags: apache-flex, augmented-reality

Is there any tutorial of how we can take a picture of augmented reality application in Flex, like in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmogH4tp0Vw)   at 1:12 min . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a post about face recognition](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fas3coder.blogspot.com%2F2010%2F08%2Factionscript-30.html&sl=ru&tl=en&hl=&ie=UTF-8), just replace the recognition criteria to the hand.